# How to fix Cyrillic encoding in Telegram bot on Google Cloud?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I made a telegram bot, launched it on a server on Ubuntu from Google Cloud.
But the bot in Russian (Cyrillic) has problems with the encoding.

The config of the text workers for the bot is saved in UTF-8, the language pack for RU is installed on the server.

There is a suspicion that on the server the encoding in the files is broken and the problem with the google cloud server is associated with rather than with the bot. What could be the problem?

[image: Screenshot of incorrect character display]

Comment: I just tried sending a message from my bot to the user, who initiated the conversion with that bot. I tried sending both in english and russian, and both messages rendered just fine in my case on the user side. I think you would need to provide some more info, eg a minimal reproducible example before anyone could tell you what is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

From the picture, I cannot verify the hex values of individual bytes, but this looks like it might actually be UTF-8 being mis-interpreted as something else.

Maybe something is sending wrong metadata, like specifying the character set as some legacy 8-bit character set, and the receiver will believe that instead of auto-detecting it as UTF-8?

Or maybe the character set has not been specified in some configuration file, and whatever creates the metadata (e.g. the character set in the Content-Type header output by a HTTP server) will apply some old stupid default value, like ISO-8859-1?